# Crash on iOS6 presentViewController: but not on iOS5

Tags: xcode, viewcontroller, ios6

This code is crashing when i run my app on iOS6 Simulator with Xcode 4.5 GM Seeds:

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] isEqualToString:@"6.0"]) {
    XLog(@"hier checken");

    self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

}

[...]

self.loginController = [[[LoginController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginController_iPhone" bundle:nil] autorelease];

self.loginController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;

//this line occurs a crash on iOS 6 (simulator, device not tested)
[self.tabBarController presentViewController:self.loginController
                                        animated:YES
                                      completion:nil];
```

The crash is a SIGABRT. no more information about the crash.

what is occuring this crash on iOS6?

Comment: can you post the crash log? (even if its just SIGABRT) ?

Comment: i am not getting any crash log in console.

Comment: only thing I could suggest is to comment everything, and then uncomment one line, run, and continue the cycle until it crashes (or you could just step through it with a breakpoint). You'll know why its crashing

Comment: I was having a similar issue. Just to be sure, are you using the address book in your logincontroller?

Comment: the issue is somewhere in the Xib. there is something new in Xcode 4.5 with the xibs, i think. but still didnt find out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`initWithNibName:bundle:` is the designated initializer for a UIViewController,and there is something new in iOS6 .

You can try to modify your LoginController_iPhone.xib and remove its controller :

[image] **---->**  [image]

It works for me .
hope this helps.

Comment: i also tried it with all my view controllers, after that i have new errors, so this issue is fixed. thats the correct answer, thank you!

Answer (score -1):

An app i was working on, would crash without any trace when I was trying to access the address book. ABAddressBookRef or ABAddressBookCreate with the permission for your app to access Contacts turned off, will crash the app. Hope this helps!

Comment: i dont use address book in my app. the issue is anything different.

Comment: Look for any deprecated apis you are using in the LoginViewController.  Most of the iOS6 related crashses I have been coming across, which have no trace, are related to this. I wish there was a list of deprecated APIs for every new OS released. btw, trying turning the "treat warnings as errors" option in the compiler settings. That should show you which deprecated APIs you are using

Comment: i have no warnings in xcode. have worked all deprecated warnings out. what i dont understand: `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation`is deprecated, but i dont get warnings for this method. any idea?

Comment: unfortunately, I didnt get any warning for the address book method either. I am not sure if its a bug in the IDE, or if I am missing something.